# zendframework/zendsearch package unavailable when trying to install it via composer

Tags: lucene, zend-framework2, zend-search-lucene

anyone please give me detail instructions on installing ZendSearch package as the official documentation is incomplete.. Zendsearch package unavailable when trying to install it via composer.

The composer returned with the message "The requested package zendframework/zendsearch could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name."

Comment: found the solution on [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290056/install-zendsearch-in-zf2-skeleton-application